# Python Pandas: remove entries based on the number of occurrences

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to remove entries from a data frame which occur less than 100 times. 
The data frame `data` looks like this:

```
pid   tag
1     23    
1     45
1     62
2     24
2     45
3     34
3     25
3     62
```

Now I count the number of tag occurrences like this:

```
bytag = data.groupby('tag').aggregate(np.count_nonzero)
```

But then I can't figure out how to remove those entries which have low count...

Comment: As [@unutbu suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446480/python-pandas-remove-entries-based-on-the-number-of-occurrences/18357933#comment33532766_18357933), please consider changing the accepted answer on this (filter method is simpler :) )

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Edit: Thanks to @WesMcKinney for showing this much more direct way:

```
data[data.groupby('tag').pid.transform(len) > 1]
```

---

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
data = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'pid' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
     'tag' : [23,45,62,24,45,34,25,62],
     })

bytag = data.groupby('tag').aggregate(np.count_nonzero)
tags = bytag[bytag.pid >= 2].index
print(data[data['tag'].isin(tags)])
```

yields

```
   pid  tag
1    1   45
2    1   62
4    2   45
7    3   62
```

Comment: a cute one-liner: data[data.groupby('tag').pid.transform(len) > 1]

Comment: We now have the [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#filtration) method for this.

Comment: What if I have another columns says "userid". I want select only those data, where a pid has more than 100 and entries and at the same time, uid has more that 100 entries.
I tried & only group by, but it doesn't seems to be working.

reviews_imp_pr =  reviews_imp[(reviews_imp.groupby('author')['score'].count() > 50) & (reviews_imp.groupby('product')['score'].count() > 50) ]

Answer (score 36):

New in 0.12, groupby objects have a [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#filtration) method, allowing you to do these types of operations:

```
In [11]: g = data.groupby('tag')

In [12]: g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)  # pandas 0.13.1
Out[12]:
   pid  tag
1    1   45
2    1   62
4    2   45
7    3   62
```

*The function (the first argument of filter) is applied to each group (subframe), and the results include elements of the original DataFrame belonging to groups which evaluated to True.*

Note: [in 0.12 the ordering is different than in the original DataFrame](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4621), this was fixed in 0.13+:

```
In [21]: g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)  # pandas 0.12
Out[21]: 
   pid  tag
1    1   45
4    2   45
2    1   62
7    3   62
```

Comment: I wonder if the ordering of the result not being in the same order is intentional...

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this question to preach the gospel of filter. The reordering is a known issue that I should have included in the docs. The order *is* maintained if you set ``dropna=False``. If not, the groups may be shuffled. Resorting them would cost time, so I left that to the user, which was a debatable choice.

Comment: @DanAllan Also if there is repeated/unordered index it may be non-trivial to put them back in order. Ah ha, currently you can do: `g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, dropna=False).dropna()` to keep the order.

Comment: @DanAllan oh no you can't... as reindexing doesn't work with repeats. So filter doesn't work. Mind you, nor does transform.

Comment: If anyone else is reading, link to bug report re repeats: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4620

Comment: @sashkello: Please consider making this the accepted answer. It is simpler and is the right way to do it going forward.

Comment: Wes McKinney's `groupby` `transform` is more than 2x faster than using `filter`

Comment: @zbinsd please share your benchmark code! I haven't checked this recently, but it did not used to be the case.

Comment: @AndyHayden - Sure! I added a new answer

Answer (score 8):

Here are some run times for a couple of the solutions posted here, along with one that was not (using `value_counts()`) that is much faster than the other solutions:

### Create the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate some 'users'
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid': np.random.randint(0, 500, 500)})

# Prove that some entries are 1
print "{:,} users only occur once in dataset".format(sum(df.uid.value_counts() == 1))
```

#### Output:

`171 users only occur once in dataset`

#### Time a few different ways of removing users with only one entry. These were run in separate cells in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
%%timeit
df.groupby(by='uid').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

%%timeit
df[df.groupby('uid').uid.transform(len) > 1]

%%timeit
vc = df.uid.value_counts()
df[df.uid.isin(vc.index[vc.values > 1])].uid.value_counts()
```

#### These gave the following outputs:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 46.2 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 30.1 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop
```

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. The one using value_counts() is *much* faster than the other two especially for datasets that have a large number of groups

Comment: Last method was pretty fast in 30M data. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to slice the dataset ant take only the values > 1, just

vc = df.uid.value_counts()

df = df[df.uid.isin(vc.index[vc.values > 1])]

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1),(2,2,)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     3
2     1     4
3     2     1
4     2     2

gp = df.groupby('col1').aggregate(np.count_nonzero)

In [38]: gp
Out[38]: 
      col2
col1      
1        3
2        2
```

lets get where the count > 2

```
tf = gp[gp.col2 > 2].reset_index()
df[df.col1 == tf.col1]

Out[41]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     3
2     1     4
```

Comment: Now I've got the idea. Another way of doing this could be to join these data frames, it will remove the non-matching entries and I can drop count column afterwards.

Comment: jep that would work 2. i usually just use a mask and then select the cols i need