# Delete a group after pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to delete a group (by group name) from a groupby object in pandas? That is, after performing a groupby, delete a resulting group based on its name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Filtering a DataFrame groupwise has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446480/python-pandas-remove-entries-based-on-the-number-of-occurrences#comment18556837_13447176). And a future release of pandas may include [a more convenient way to do it](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3680).

But currently, here is what I believe to be the most succinct way to filter the GroupBy object `grouped` by name and return a DataFrame of the remaining groups.

```
df.drop(grouped.get_group(group_name).index)
```

And here is a more general method derived from the links above:

```
df[grouped[0].transform(lambda x: x.name != group_name).astype('bool')]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That was a bit more obvious than I was hoping -- not too painful.

Comment: Doesn't this require that we "re-create" the groups because we are only altering the df? Have their been any developments that allows us to do this more easily?

Answer (score 2):

Seems there's no direct way to delete a group from a groupby object. I think you can filter out those groupby before groupby by

```
df = df[df[group] != group_name]
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what is meant by the variable ``group``, but you can't index a DataFrame by a GroupBy object.

Comment: I think it should be `df = df[df[group_name] != group_label]. But the poster have use group_name ad group_label

Comment: How do you make group_name?

Answer (score 2):

it is so simple, you need to use the filter function and lambda exp:

`df_filterd=df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x:(x.name == 'cond1' or...(other condtions )))`

you need to take care that if you want to use more than condtion to put it in brackets()..
and you will get back a DataFrame not GroupObject.

Answer (score -1):

Should be easy:

`df.drop(index='group_name',inplace=True)`