# Skip the first group in a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas df that I have grouped, like so:

`gQ = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['Quantity']`

and it returns:

`0  0      135.68
   1     1054.68
   2      101.12
1  3      131.74
   4     1025.47
   5       97.40
2  6     1078.07
   7      101.93
3  8     1075.92
   9      102.06
4  10    1085.37
   11     102.80
   12    1656.58
5  13    1081.65
   14     104.27
   15    1659.42
Name: Price, dtype: float64`

I want values from all groups except the first group, i.e.,

`0  0      135.68
   1     1054.68
   2      101.12`

Is it possible to filter out just that?

Comment: Please add input data to be able to re-create your dataframe

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226142/python-pandas-delete-the-first-row-by-group), it might be relevant here.

Comment: Please refer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910114/delete-a-group-after-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 0):

Use MultiIndex and levels - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html - there are many examples: choose the best for your needs. BR