# Remove first and last group from python pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have some timeseries data

```
time x   y
1s   34  8017  
1s   43  5019
1s   1   8017
2s   64  8870
2s   34  8305
2s   11  8305
3s   343 8221
3s   3   8221
3s   143 8221
```

that I grouped by `df.groupby(data.index.second)` using python pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Producing 3 groups where group 1 looks like this which corresponds to the first second

```
time x   y
1s   34  8017  
1s   43  5019
1s   1   8017
```

How can I remove the first group (1th second) and the last group (3th second)?

I only want this group (group 2)

```
time x   y
2s   64  8870
2s   34  8305
2s   11  8305
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910114/delete-a-group-after-pandas-groupby) without success and maybe the groupby function is not the way to go.

Comment: Probably easiest to filter them out before grouping the data frame. Something like `df = df[(df['second'] != 1 & df['second'] != 3)]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or a better solution:

```
data = data.drop(data[data.timestamp.dt.second == data.iloc[0][0].second].index)
data = data.drop(data[data.timestamp.dt.second == data.iloc[-1][0].second].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
df2 = df[df['time']=='2s']
```

This will remove both `'1s'` and `'3s'` from your main `df` and then we can store it in new variable which we can all `df2`

Comment: My example wasn't the best... What if I have multiple of seconds in between e.g. 22s to 30s, then I want to remove the 22s and 30s groups but not 23s,24s,25s... groups

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by saving all the keys

```py
l = list(df.groupby(data.index.second))
```

and then deleting the first and last key from the list

```
del l[0]
del l[-1]
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Answer (score 0):

I note that you answered your own question, but perhaps this is of some use: using `filter`,

```
df.groupby('time').filter(lambda g: g.name not in ['1s','3s'])
```

produces

```
    time    x   y
3   2s     64   8870
4   2s     34   8305
5   2s     11   8305
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all unique `time`s without first and last unique values in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['time'].isin(df['time'].unique()[1:-1])]
print (df)
  time   x     y
3   2s  64  8870
4   2s  34  8305
5   2s  11  8305
```