# Pandas: DataFrame filtering using groupby and a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using Python 3.3 and Pandas 0.10

I have a DataFrame that is built from concatenating multiple CSV files. First, I filter out all values in the Name column that contain a certain string. The result looks something like this (shortened for brevity sakes, actually there are more columns):

```
Name    ID
'A'     1
'B'     2
'C'     3
'C'     3
'E'     4
'F'     4
...     ...
```

Now my issue is that I want to remove a special case of 'duplicate' values. I want to remove all ID duplicates (entire row actually) where the corresponding Name values that are mapped to this ID are **not** similar. In the example above I would like to keep rows with ID 1, 2 and 3. Where ID=4 the Name values are unequal and I want to remove those.

I tried to use the following line of code (based on the suggestion here: [Python Pandas: remove entries based on the number of occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446480/python-pandas-remove-entries-based-on-the-number-of-occurrences#comment18556837_13447176)).

Code:

```
df[df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: len({x for x in g['Name']})) == 1]
```

However that gives me the error:
`ValueError: Item wrong length 51906 instead of 109565!`

Edit:

Instead of using `apply()` I have also tried using `transform()`, however that gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. An explanation on why the error is different per function is very much appreciated!

Also, I want to keep keep all rows where ID = 3 in the above example.

Thanks in advance,
Matthijs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of length `len`, I think you want to consider the number of unique values of Name in each group. Use `nunique()`, and check out this neat recipe for filtering groups.

```
df[df.groupby('ID').Name.transform(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1).astype('bool')]
```

If you upgrade to pandas 0.12, you can use the new `filter` method on groups, which makes this more succinct and straightforward.

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x.Name.nunique() == 1)
```

A general remark: Sometimes, of course, you do want to know the length of the group, but I find that `size` is a safer choice than `len`, which has been troublesome for me in some cases.

Comment: I always forget about transform! :)

Comment: Haha. People often do not discover it -- I think I answer transform questions at least weekly.

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks! I'll have to try your code tomorrow but so far it makes sense to me. I didn't know about `nunique()` so thanks for pointing that out as well. Actually, could you briefly describe why you're using `transform()` as opposed to `apply()`?

Comment: ``apply`` would return a shorter Series, with one entry per group. Instead, we want a Series of the same length as the original one, with each group's entire contents mapped to ``True`` or ``False`` as a block. Then we can use that boolean Series to mask the original Series. See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation) for more.

Comment: Hi Dan, I just ran your code and it works like a charm. Thanks also for the explanation on `transform()` versus `apply()`!

Answer (score 0):

You could first drop the duplicates:

```
In [11]: df = df.drop_duplicates()

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  Name ID
0    A  1
1    B  2
2    C  3
4    E  4
5    F  4
```

The `groupby` id and only consider those with one element:

```
In [13]: g = df.groupby('ID')

In [14]: size = (g.size() == 1)

In [15]: size
Out[15]:
ID
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
dtype: bool

In [16]: size[size].index
Out[16]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)

In [17]: df['ID'].isin(size[size].index)
Out[17]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
4    False
5    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

And boolean index by this:

```
In [18]: df[df['ID'].isin(size[size].index)]
Out[18]:
  Name ID
0    A  1
1    B  2
2    C  3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy, but I'll go with Dan's answer.