# Python/Pandas: Split DataFrame and Recombine Only Groups that Have More than One Unique Value

Tags: python, pandas, split, group-by, apply

My DataFrame has ContactID and AutoNumber columns. Every ContactID can have more than one associated AutoNumber. I want to exclude all of the of ContactID's that only have one AutoNumber from my DataFrame.

I tried this:

```
data = data.groupby('ContactID').filter(lambda g: g.AutoNumber.nunique() > 1)
```

However, there are still ContactID's with only 1 AutoNumber.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: DataFrame filtering using groupby and a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950835/pandas-dataframe-filtering-using-groupby-and-a-function)