# Pandas equivalent of GROUP BY HAVING in SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, group-by, filtering

What is the most efficient way to use groupby and in parallel apply a filter in pandas?

Basically I am asking for the equivalent in SQL of

```sql
select *
...
group by col_name
having condition
```

I think there are many uses cases ranging from conditional means, sums, conditional probabilities, etc. which would make such a command very powerful.

I need a very good performance, so ideally such a command would not be the result of several layered operations done in python.

Comment: @AndyHayden has written a [nice example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18357933/190597) of using `groupby-filter`. I think the `filter` is the pandas equivalent of the `having condition`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As mentioned in unutbu's comment, [groupby's filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) is the equivalent of SQL'S HAVING:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  5  6

In [13]: g = df.groupby('A')  #  GROUP BY A

In [14]: g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)  #  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
Out[14]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
```

You can write more complicated functions (these are applied to each group), provided they return a plain ol' bool:

```
In [15]: g.filter(lambda x: x['B'].sum() == 5)
Out[15]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
```

*Note: [potentially there is a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6512) where you can't write you function to act on the columns you've used to groupby... a workaround is the groupby the columns manually i.e. `g = df.groupby(df['A']))`.*

Comment: maybe add to the Comparison with SQL section? (this example)

Comment: @Jeff good call, looking at it, I wonder if should think about example of using agg *and* filter at the same time (I don't think there is a way to do that easily without doing a second groupby...) that could be this question :s

Comment: just chain em (but you do need a second groupby): ``DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 5], [2, 8], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B']).groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1).groupby('A').sum()``

Comment: For more complicated cases I had to use `.apply()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394476/keep-other-columns-when-using-min-with-groupby/49476152#49476152

Comment: Unfortunately, `filter` "flattens" the DataFrameGroupBy object into a DataFrame, so you’ll have to group by twice if you want to act on the groups you selected.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the most efficient way to use groupby and in parallel apply a filter in pandas?

## Use `groupby.transform` + boolean indexing

Even though the equivalent syntax in pandas is `groupby.filter`, it is painfully slow. If performance is important, instead of filtering *during* the groupby operation, it's far better to perform the groupby and filter the dataframe later. Because `groupby.filter` makes calls to Python functions (e.g. lambda) for each group while `groupby.transform` calls a Cython-optimized function on the entire dataframe, the latter is much faster if there are a lot of groups.

The point of using `groupby.transform` is that it returns a dataframe that has the same indexes as the original dataframe filled with the aggregated values. Since its output has the same index, it can be used to filter the original dataframe.

So the equivalent of

```sql
SELECT * FROM df GROUP BY colA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

is

```py
df[df.groupby('colA').transform('size') > 1]
```

and the equivalent of

```sql
SELECT * FROM df GROUP BY colA HAVING SUM(colB) > 5
```

is

```py
df[df.groupby('colA')['colB'].transform('sum') > 5]
```

Anyway, as the following performance graph shows, as the number of groups increase, `groupby.transform` + boolean indexing performs much faster than `groupby.filter`; for example with 10k groups, it is 1000 times faster. In fact, if your dataframe has millions of groups, `groupby.filter` may not even run while `groupby.transform` + boolean indexing will finish the job in reasonable amount of time.

[image: result]

Code used to produce the above graph

```py
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def groupby_filter(df):
    g = df.groupby('A')
    return g.filter(lambda x: x['B'].sum() > 5)

def groupby_transform(df):
    g = df.groupby('A')
    return df[g['B'].transform('sum') > 5]


perfplot.plot(
    kernels=[groupby_filter, groupby_transform],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(16)],
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({
        'A': np.random.choice(n, size=n, replace=False), 
        'B': np.random.randint(n, size=n)}),
    xlabel='Number of groups'
)
```

Comment: You deserve a lot more upvotes! Also TIL about `perfplot`, very cool.

Answer (score 0):

I group by state and county where max is greater than 20 then subquery the resulting values for True using the dataframe loc

```
counties=df.groupby(['state','county'])['field1'].max()>20
counties=counties.loc[counties.values==True]
```