# How to separate the pandas table into separate groups?

Tags: python

I am struggling to separate the data. I tried looking at the groupby function pandas has, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
data = pd.read_csv("path/file")
y=data['JIN-DIF']
y1=data['JEX-DIF']
y2=data['JEL-DIF']
y3=data['D3E']
d={'Induction':y,'Exchange':y1,'Dispersion':y3,'Electrostatic':y2}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
grouped_df2= df.groupby('Exchange')
grouped_df2.filter(lambda x: x.Exchange > 0)
```

When I run this code, I get an  "TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool error". I'm not sure about how to upload the data, so I have just attached a picture of it.
It will work when I change line 9 to

```
grouped_df2.filter(lambda x: x.Exchange.mean() > 0)
```

Here is a picture of sample data

[image]

The error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-0e26eb8f080b> in <module>
      7 df=pd.DataFrame(d)
      8 grouped_df2= df.groupby('Exchange')
----> 9 grouped_df2.filter(lambda x: x.Exchange > -0.1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in filter(self, func, dropna, *args, **kwargs)
   1584                 # non scalars aren't allowed
   1585                 raise TypeError(
-> 1586                     f"filter function returned a {type(res).__name__}, "
   1587                     "but expected a scalar bool"
   1588                 )

TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

Comment: you may want to change the third line from `y=`... to `y1=...`. I don't know if this is the source of the error, but you did not define `y1`...

Comment: also, what line gives you the error? Number 6?

Comment: For some reason i can't seem to edit the post. It is line 9

Comment: which makes me even more suspicious. 'Exchange' is the key to `y1`, which you did not defined. Who is `y1` in your code?

Comment: Also: have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045706/pandas-filter-function-returned-a-series-but-expected-a-scalar-bool)? It was the first thing coming out by googling your error

Comment: It was a misedit. I had previously defined it all properly, but as I was moving it into one block I just mislabeled it in the process.

Comment: grouped_df2= df.groupby('Exchange').filter(lambda x: x.count > -0.1)                    should be the line that I would run, but I then get this error                                             TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'float'

Comment: What does google say about this new, different, error?

Comment: Brings me to other questions that have different issues.