# Drop Rows Only first Value left in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row

I am a Newbie in python. I have a big `dataframe` looks like this:

```
ID  A   B   C
A   12331   A1  CA
A   23445   A1  CA
A   38650   A1  CA
B   12324   B1  BB
B   45356   B1  BB
B   97867   B1  BB
C   34563   C1  CC
C   64577   C1  CC
C   74533   C1  CC
```

how to delete or drop the row but first (minimum value) still exist. I tried this [Keep other columns when using min() with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394476/keep-other-columns-when-using-min-with-groupby) but still not working.  my expected result looks like this:

```
ID  A   B   C
A   12331   A1  CA
B   12324   B1  BB
C   34563   C1  CC
```

thank you

Comment: Given that minimum values occur at first place and each category (A, B, ..) have 3 entries then just use `df.iloc[::3,0]`

Comment: Do you try `df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['A'].idxmin()]` ? For me it working nice.