# Add group by result to parent table with index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by, addition

This question got closed, but the mentioned question [Keep other columns when doing groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394476/keep-other-columns-when-doing-groupby) with the solution does not work for me.

I want to group by the child df on `animals` get the min `birth_dates`, apply this date to the colum `date_of_birth` to the the parent df where the `animal` is the index.

the child table :

| Animals | ... | Brithdates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Frog | ... | 2021-02-10 |
| Frog | ... | 2021-02-12 |
| Tiger | ... | 2010-04-08 |
| Tiger | ... | 2008-06-10 |
| Fish | ... | 2005-12-10 |
| Rabbit | ... | 2015-05-15 |

the parent table :

| index | ... | date_of_brith |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Frog | ... | 2021-02-10 |
| Tiger | ... | 2008-06-10 |
| Fish | ... | 2005-12-10 |
| Rabbit | ... | 2015-05-15 |

At the moment  I came up with the following steps:
To get the min date_of_brith of each animal group.
`child_df.groupby('ANIMALS').brith_dates.min()`

`parent_df['date_of_birth']= parent_df['date_of_birth'].loc[child_df.groupby('ANIMALS').brith_dates.min()]`

this gives me an error, how could I add the results to each specific index to the corresponding colum ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
s = child_df.groupby('Animals').Brithdates.min()

parent_df['date_of_birth'] = parent_df.index.map(s)
print (parent_df)
        ... date_of_brith date_of_birth
index                                  
Frog    ...    2021-02-10    2021-02-10
Tiger   ...    2008-06-10    2008-06-10
Fish    ...    2005-12-10    2005-12-10
Rabbit  ...    2015-05-15    2015-05-15
```

Comment: thank you it worked.  i made it do a one line with:
parent_df['date_of_birth'] = parent_df.index.map(child_df.groupby('ANIMALS').brith_dates.min())