# Getting all NaT values for Pandas calc that searches for Max Date by Group

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

code

```
reviewer_map['Max Date of Review'] = reviewer_map.groupby('UserID_NB').agg({'Date of Review': [np.max]})
```

dtypes

```
UserID_NB                     object
Technical Director            object
Date of Review        datetime64[ns]
Max Date of Review    datetime64[ns]
```

output looks like

```
UserID_NB       Technical Director      Date of Review      Max Date of Review
FRANK1          Frank                   2017-04-20          NaT
JOHN2           John                    2017-04-20          NaT
```

I'd like to show the date of each review along with the director and id number of the reviewer. I've got some duplicates from reschedules so I'm trying to limit this list to the most recent date value for each `USERID_NB`. For some reason my max values are coming back as missing.

Comment: can you proviide a minimal (copyable) input that shows this behaviour (see [mcve])?

Comment: If I'm following this correctly you're asking for a dataset that replicates the problem, correct?

Comment: Exactly :) Doesn't need to be your dataset, just something that can be used to get a similar (problematic) result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby()` in this case returns a data frame, not a column to be added to an existing data frame.  That's why you were getting missing values in `Max Date of Review`.
It also seems you don't really need both `Date of Review` and `Max Date of Review` in your final output.
Additionally, `'max'` is sufficient as an `agg()` function, you don't need `np.max`, nor do you need to wrap it in a list.

You basically already solved your own problem, minus a few syntax issues.  It's easy enough to set straight.

First, here's some sample data:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20170101', periods=6, freq='D')
uid = ['FRANK1','JOHN2','FRANK1','JOHN2','FRANK1','FRANK1']
name = ['Frank','John','Frank','JohnABC','Frank','Frank123']
reviewer_map = pd.DataFrame({'UserID_NB':uid,
                             'Technical Director':name,
                             'Date of Review':dates})

print(reviewer_map)
  Date of Review Technical Director UserID_NB
0     2017-01-01              Frank    FRANK1
1     2017-01-02               John     JOHN2
2     2017-01-03              Frank    FRANK1
3     2017-01-04            JohnABC     JOHN2
4     2017-01-05              Frank    FRANK1
5     2017-01-06           Frank123    FRANK1
```

If you want to use `groupby()` to accomplish your goal, this will work:

```
print(reviewer_map.groupby('UserID_NB', as_index=False)
                  .agg({'Date of Review': 'max'})
                  .rename(columns={'Date of Review':'Max Date of Review'}))

  UserID_NB Max Date of Review
0    FRANK1         2017-01-06
1     JOHN2         2017-01-04
```

Note that the `rename()` at the end isn't strictly necessary, it's only for if you actually want to rename the `Date of Review` column as `Max Date of Review`.

**UPDATE**
Per OP comments, here's a version that includes the `Technical Director` field that matches the `max` `Date of Review`.  Note that the SQL `having` syntax [can sometimes be mimicked with `filter()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107169/2799941), but it's not always a straightforwardly analogous operation and often requires multiple `groupby` operations.

Here I used `merge()` instead, which matches the `Technical Director` values from the original data frame with the max date rows of the `groupby` output.  Example data  now includes different `Technical Director` values per `UserID_NB`, in order to illustrate this update.

```
df = (reviewer_map.groupby('UserID_NB', as_index=False)
              .agg({'Date of Review': 'max'}))
df.merge(reviewer_map, 
         on=['UserID_NB','Date of Review'], 
         how='left')
```

Output:

```
  UserID_NB Date of Review Technical Director
0    FRANK1     2017-01-06           Frank123
1     JOHN2     2017-01-04            JohnABC
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. If I did want Max Date of Review in my output (I only want to keep those entries where the Date of Review = Max Date of Review) how would I do that?

Comment: You're welcome!  Not sure I understand your question here though.  `Max Date of Review` *is* the output - the `agg()` here only returns those entries where `Date of Review == Max Date of Review`.  See the example output - only the max dates for each `UserID_NB` are returned.

Comment: I get what youre saying. My example omitted that technical director and userID_nb aren't always the same, which is why I was grouping by userID_nb (my bad).

my ideal output set would look like:

userID_NB      Technical Director      Max Date of Review

Comment: if I'd done this in sql itd look like

    select userid, techdirector, date of review 
    from dataset 
    group by userid_nb
    having max(date of review) = date of review

if that helps

Comment: yes it does! thanks again. only thing I had to change was the join (switched the df and reviewer_map so reviewer_map was on the left side)

Comment: Glad I could help.  If this answer adequately resolved your issue,  please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.