# Pandas groupby take counts greater than 1

Tags: python, pandas

This must be a simple question, but, however, it is bugging my head for a while.

For a dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c0': ['a','b','a'],'c1': ['a','bb','a'],'c2':[10,20,30]})
  c0  c1  c2
0  a   a  10
1  b  bb  20
2  a   a  30
```

How to get output where count > 1?

I have tried:

```
df.groupby(['c0','c1'])['c2'].count()
c0  c1
a   a     2
b   bb    1
```

Required is:

```
c0  c1
a   a     2
```

I am looking other than

```
x = df.groupby(['c0','c1'])['c2'].count()
x[x>1]
```

i.e. a one-liner answer.

Comment: Related: [Pandas equivalent of GROUP BY HAVING in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77513588/19123103)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original DataFrame:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(['c0','c1'])['c2'].transform('count') > 1]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for filtered all dupe rows by specified columns in list:

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated(['c0','c1'], keep=False)]
```

If performance is in not important or small DataFrame use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['c0','c1']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

Comment: Which one is best, I guess  the duplicated one?

Comment: @astro123 - If you think the fastest the best test, but second solution should be winner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one-liner:

```py
In [8]: df.groupby(['c0','c1'])['c2'].count().pipe(lambda  dfx: dfx.loc[dfx>1])
Out[8]: 
c0  c1
a   a     2
Name: c2, dtype: int64
```