# Boolean indexing with dict lookup

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with batch numbers and I want to exclude entries that appear less than x times.
Let us say x is 3 for and the dataframe looks like this:

```
   BatchName
0   001
1   001
2   001
3   002
4   002
5   003
6   003
7   003
```

As far as I know, I cannot use Boolean indexing straight up because the column contains no information about the other columns.
I therfore created a countdict using

```
Countdict = dict(df.groupby('BatchName')['BatchPosition'].count()
```

Where 'BatchPosition' is another column uninteresting to this problem.

I then try to do Boolean indexing with the dataframe like:

```
df[Countdict[df['BatchName'] >= 3 ]
```

This however does not work as I hoped because it tries to put the hole Series into the dict.
How do I make it put each value from the Series into the dict instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby take counts greater than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360314/pandas-groupby-take-counts-greater-than-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem there is different size of aggregate Series after `df.groupby('BatchName')['BatchPosition'].count()`, you can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for mask with same size like original `df`:

```
df[df['BatchName'].map(df['BatchName'].value_counts()) >= 3]
```

Your solution should be changed by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df[df.groupby('BatchName')['BatchName'].transform('count') >= 3]
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['BatchName'].map(df['BatchName'].value_counts()))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
Name: BatchName, dtype: int64

print (df['BatchName'].map(df['BatchName'].value_counts()) >= 3)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: BatchName, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print (df.groupby('BatchName')['BatchName'].transform('count'))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
Name: BatchName, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('BatchName')['BatchName'].transform('count') >= 3)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: BatchName, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess i have to study the .map and .value_counts functions some more :)