# Selection errors with a Boolean

Tags: python, pandas, select, boolean

I have a dataset called `no_borough` with street information.

I'm trying to select only the streets that appear more than once. When I run `no_borough['ON STREET NAME'].value_counts() > 1`, I produce the following:

```
BELT PARKWAY                         True
LONG ISLAND EXPRESSWAY               True
BROOKLYN QUEENS EXPRESSWAY           True
GRAND CENTRAL PKWY                   True
FDR DRIVE                            True
                                    ...  
HARVEST AVENUE                      False
6th Ave                             False
W 23rd St                           False
CRYDERS LANE                        False
WINFIELD STREET                     False
Name: ON STREET NAME, Length: 4890, dtype: bool
```

But when I try to select with this Boolean, using either

```
no_borough[(no_borough['ON STREET NAME'].value_counts() > 1) == True]
```

I receive a

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

When  I try

```
no_borough[no_borough['ON STREET NAME'].value_counts() > 1]
```

I receive a

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

What is the correct way to perform this selection?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360314/pandas-groupby-take-counts-greater-than-1

Answer (score 0):

One way is;

```
no_borough['ON STREET NAME'].value_counts()[lambda x:x>1]
```

Alternatively use `duplicated()`

```
no_borough[no_borough['ON STREET NAME'].duplicated()]
```