# I want to apply group by over a dataframe and filter it throug the mean whose value is greater than any given number

Tags: python, pandas

In SQL, we apply a filter over aggregated function like below

```sql
select col1,avg(col2) as avg_col2 from table group by col1 having avg_col2>100;
```

how can I apply the same logic in pandas over data frame?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105452/pandas-what-is-the-equivalent-of-sql-group-by-having

Comment: Thank you @Rajan Sharma