# Can I select rows based on group size with pandas? Or do I have to use SQL?

Tags: python, pandas

With pandas I can do grouping using `df.groupby('product_name').size()`. But if I'm only interested rows whose "product_name" is unique, i.e. those records with groupby.size equal to one, how can I filter the df to see only such rows? In other words, can I perform filtering on a database using pandas, based on the number of times an attribute occurs in the database? (I could do that with SQL alright.)

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: remove entries based on the number of occurrences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446480/python-pandas-remove-entries-based-on-the-number-of-occurrences)

Comment: Thank you both. I still haven't been able to get it to work, despite it sounding like a straightforward operation. But it's good for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work with `records.groupby('product_name').filter(lambda x: len(x['url']) == 1)`. Note that simply using `len(x)` doesn't work. With a dataframe with more than two columns (which is probably most of the real-life dataframes), one has to specify a column for x: any column, except the one to group by with. Also, this code initially didn't work for me because my index on the dataframe was not unique. I'm not sure why this should interfere with the function of filtering, but it did. After reindexing the dataframe, I finally got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have found `transform` to be much more efficient than `filter` for very large dataframes:

```
row_group_sizes = (
    df['product_name']
    .groupby(df['product_name'])
    .transform('size')
)

df[row_group_sizes==1]
```

Or, in one line:

```
df[df['product_name'].groupby(df['product_name']).transform('size')==1]
```