# Pandas: Can pandas groupby filter work on original object?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

Starting with this question as base.

[Python Pandas: remove entries based on the number of occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446480/python-pandas-remove-entries-based-on-the-number-of-occurrences)

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'pid' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
     'tag' : [23,45,62,24,45,34,25,62],
     })

   #    pid  tag
   # 0    1   23
   # 1    1   45
   # 2    1   62 
   # 3    2   24
   # 4    2   45
   # 5    3   34
   # 6    3   25
   # 7    3   62

   g = data.groupby('tag')
   g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1) # filters out lengths > 1. 

  #     pid  tag
  #  1    1   45
  #  2    1   62
  #  4    2   45
  #  7    3   62


 #This would create a new object g: 
 g  =   g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1) #where g is now a dataframe.
```

I was wondering is there a way to filter out 'groups' by deleting 
them from original object `g`. And, would it be faster than creating a new `groupby` object from filtered groupby.

Answer (score 1):

There is only so many ways you can solve this problem. My answer includes   4 solutions. I am sure, there are other ways. Maybe some other answers will present a better way.

**Solution #1:**

```
data = data.groupby('tag').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
   pid  tag
1   1   45
2   1   62
4   2   45
7   3   62
```

**Solution #2:**

```
data['count'] = data.groupby(['tag']).transform('count')
data.loc[data['count'] == 2]
   pid  tag     count
1   1   45  2
2   1   62  2
4   2   45  2
7   3   62  2
```

**Solution #3:**

If you want to delete the rows instead, you can use `.index.tolist()` and then `drop()`.

```
data['count'] = data.groupby(['tag']).transform('count')
data.drop(data[data['count'] != 2].index.tolist())
   pid  tag     count
1   1   45  2
2   1   62  2
4   2   45  2
7   3   62  2
```

**Solution #4:**

```
data['count'] = data.groupby(['tag']).transform('count')
g = data.groupby('count')
data.loc[g.groups[2],('tag','pid')]
   tag  pid
1   45  1
2   62  1
4   45  2
7   62  3
```

Comment: That is no different from above -- returns a dataframe. I would need to recreate  the groupby object.

Comment: @Merlin I added an other solution.

Comment: .@Joe I am trying to delete the un-needed keys from the data.groupby('tag') object. So, I can re-use it. Not create another "g" object.

Comment: @Merlin You can `drop()` the rows you don't need. Please see my edit.

Comment: .@Joe, Since I have groupby object, which has scanned rows of the dataFrame. I think there has to be a way to delete the keys, rather than delete -drop rows. Make sense?

Comment: @Merlin Ok, take a look at my solution #4. There isn't really a whole lot more ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options (yours is at the bottom):

This first one is `inplace` and as quick as I could make it.  Its a bit quicker than your solution but not by virtue of dropping rows in place.  I can get even better performance with the second option and this does not change in place.

```
%%timeit
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'pid' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
     'tag' : [23,45,62,24,45,34,25,62],
     })

mask = ~data.duplicated(subset=['tag'], keep=False)
data.drop(mask[mask].index, inplace=True)
data

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'pid' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
     'tag' : [23,45,62,24,45,34,25,62],
     })

data = data.loc[data.duplicated(subset=['tag'], keep=False)]
data

1000 loops, best of 3: 719 µs per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'pid' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
     'tag' : [23,45,62,24,45,34,25,62],
     })
g = data.groupby('tag')
g = g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
g

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop
```

Comment: Its not duplicate removal, but rather delete the keys from grouped object that is not wanted. The grouped object is need. The groupby filter method returns a DF, I have to recreate the groupby object from the  returned DF. Seems like a waste.

Comment: the duplicated "trick" is a cheeky way of identifying rows in which tag was repeated.  If you're after an efficient way to remove indices, that's a different question.  I'll get you something.

Comment: Not indices, but rather the drop keys.. I was going to brute force a for-loop with delete keys.

Comment: Not sure I understand the nuance you're after in regards to the difference between 'drop keys' and 'delete keys'.  I've got another idea that should be fruitful.  Give me a few minutes