# Group by and update based on condition python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Hello I have a pandas dataframe with an ID column and a value column.

I'd like to use vectorized code to "group" each ID and then run a function on each value of each row within the group.  If every value for a specific ID returns False from the function I want to delete the ID and all corresponding rows from the original data frame.

```
def funct1(num):
    num = num**.5
    if num - int(num) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

import pandas as pd
df = {
   'ID':['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3'],
   'Percentage':[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The end result should be:

```
df = {
   'ID':['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2'],
   'Percentage':[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Here we see that each row of ID 3 is deleted because there is no value within the group that has a int as a square root.

I also want to maintain the index because in the real data the values are not in order like this example.

The answer should return a df not a groupby object.

Thank you for the help!

Best

Comment: Tom you are downvoting my question but it is different than the question you linked to because it is not an aggregation.

Comment: I did vote to close, but I did not downvote.  In retrospect, I see that what you want to do (drop the group when a condition is met in one row) is different than what I [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13446480/13386979) (drop the group when a condition is met across the whole group).  So I apologize for that, I retracted the close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `groupby`:

```
funct1 = lambda pct: pct.pow(0.5) - pct.pow(0.5).astype(int) == 0
out = df[df['ID'].isin(df.loc[funct1(df['Percentage']), 'ID'])]
```

```
>>> out
  ID  Percentage
0  1           7
1  1           8
2  1           9
3  1          10
4  1          11
5  2          12
6  2          13
7  2          14
8  2          15
9  2          16
```

Performance

```
# @BENY
%timeit df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : any((x['Percentage']**0.5).map(float.is_integer)))
1.08 ms ± 14.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# @Corralien
%timeit df[df['ID'].isin(df.loc[funct1(df['Percentage']), 'ID'])]
651 µs ± 2.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Corralien how did you learn your pandas techniques?  Do have any recommendations to a student on how to learn fast pandas?

Comment: I have really learned Pandas by answering questions on SO since the beginning of the year although I use it regularly for my job. You can follow users like @jezrael, BENY, AnuragDabas, HenryEcker, Mozway, ... and many others and inspire proposed responses to gain efficiency and think differently (like vectorization). In summary, spend time on SO, check their profiles and answers :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `groupby` with `filter`

```
out = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : any((x['Percentage']**0.5).map(float.is_integer)))
Out[317]: 
  ID  Percentage
0  1           7
1  1           8
2  1           9
3  1          10
4  1          11
5  2          12
6  2          13
7  2          14
8  2          15
9  2          16
```

Comment: BENY thank you.  I am still working to understand the .map portion of the code.  How does float take on the value of x['Percentage']**.5?